# Remove spacing from side of Ion-card

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

im trying to remove the spacing from the sides of my ion-cards and make them 100% width. So far ive tried all i can imagine but the carrds have refused to set to 100% width. This is my code so far:

```
<ion-content class="Content">

 <ion-card  *ngFor='let rest of modifiedData' (click)="itemSelected(rest.PushPage)"  >
  <img src={{rest.image}}/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
     <h1>{{rest.name}}</h1> 
      </ion-card-title>
    <p>{{rest.text}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card> 


  <!-- floating button for maps page -->
   <ion-fab right bottom >
   <button ion-fab color="frosted" (click)="Locations()" mini><ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon></button>
 </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

And my css:

```
page-content {

    .scroll-content {
        padding-top: 0 !important;
    }

    .main-content {
        background-color: (darkish);
        box-shadow: 0px -1px 13px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    ion-card {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        position: relative;
    }


    ion-item {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to put a valide HTML/CSS and not Ionic code so we are able to see the output and help you

Comment: hi would a screenshot be of help?

Comment: no, as we need to check the code to identify how to solve the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `sass` variables provided in the Ionic API documentation. You can place the code in your `app.scss` or `theme/variables.scss` files so it takes global effect. Something like below should work.

1. For iOS

   ```
    $card-ios-margin-left: 0;
    $card-ios-margin-right: 0;
   ```
2. For Android

   ```
    $card-md-margin-left: 0;
    $card-md-margin-right: 0;
   ```
3. For Windows Phone

   ```
    $card-wp-margin-left: 0;
    $card-wp-margin-right: 0;
   ```

Comment: YES!! what i was looking for. Added them to my variable.scss(under theme) and worked like a charm!!

Comment: ok great, please pick my answer as the selected on since it works for you